# No monitor 12.04 LTS change Resolution VNC

Tags: 12.04, resolution, vnc

I have a box, that runs Ubuntu 12.04. I connect it with a VNC client. It always go down to the default resolution because I don't have a monitor connected. Is there any way I can change the resolution to like 1440x990?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Can you clarify? Does the sneetsher suggested work?